# Why lord krishna said O descendent of Bharat to Arjun?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

I have some confusion in chapter  2  verse  18

> antavanta ime dehā nityasyoktāḥ śharīriṇaḥ

> anāśhino ’prameyasya tasmād yudhyasva bhārata

> Only the material body is perishable; the embodied soul within is indestructible, immeasurable, and eternal. Therefore, fight, O descendent of Bharat.

Im not getting the meaning   of O descendent of Bharat .

Why lord krishna said  O descendent of Bharat to Arjun ?

Comment: Bharat falls in his ancestry line of Arjun.

Comment: Arjuna was born in lineage of Puru, Bharata, Hasti, Kuru, Pandu etc. thats why he is referred as decedent of of them..similarly, Krisha was born in lineage of Yadu, Madhu, Vrishin, Shura, Vasudeva etc. thats why he is referred as  decedent of of them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://qphs.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-b018e4e09204e150469902290e073255-c  You may ignore the starting point where it is mentioned that Krsna is supreme personality of godhead(everyone has different opinions ,actually this picture's source might be Gaudiya Vaishnav sect ), rest whole family tree shows that how Pandavas and Kauravas were descendants of King Bharata. [image: image of family tree]

https://twitter.com/radharamndas/status/1293012765167120386 He is vice president AND spokesperson of ISKCON KOLKATA and he endorses same picture.

Comment: Please add all relevant information as text directly in the answer, in case the link fails in the future.

Comment: @cigien - Sir now is it okay ?

Comment: Yes, this is much better, thank you.

Comment: no worries sir  :-)

Comment: You may want to add reference of the picture you have added here. Added link is not useful as it redirects to same picture from some quora link. And Quora is not authentic source.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto now fine ?